# What TERM should I use in my Docker images?

Tags: docker

When building an image, Docker complained all the time in red about TERM not being set.

So I set it to builtin_xterm (I don't remember where I got a list of possible values from, but there were many) using ENV, and now there are fewer red messages.

But then when running commands inside the container sometimes I have problems. For example when I run `$ clear` I get an error and the screen isn't cleared. Another example is `$ git diff`, I get this:

```
WARNING: terminal is not fully functional
-  (press RETURN)
```

It seems to work fine after pressing enter, but it's annoying nevertheless.

So is there any value for TERM that will eliminate all the problems?

Answer (score 2):

I personally tend to use xterm in my images, but any TERM corresponding to your real (host) term should do the job.

Comment: i.e. `export TERM=xterm`